# Standard input and output in c

Tags: c

I have a problem with stdout and stdin .when i store data by using stdout i cant getback the same data using stdin . so please help me how can i solve my problem.
                                                                     Ram

Comment: Oh dear! You seem to have totally misunderstood stdin and stdout - stdin is where you get normal input characters from - which is normally the keyboard. stdout is where normal text output goes (printf and such like) and is normally set to a terminal window on your screen. They can be redirected to other devices or files but they are normally different devices or files - why would writing to one allow you to read from the other?
I think we need to know what you are trying to do.

Comment: On some *nix you can actually write to stdin from your program and it gets appended to the steam, but this is not portable or a good idea really.

Comment: Even if stdin and stdout were connected to the same pipe (theoretically possible but unlikely), why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Data you write to stdout will not be automatically available to stdin. Data written to the stdout stream is available to be read by whatever process is connected to that stream. Normally that is the terminal or console where the program was started. It can also be another process that was connected to the first one through a pipe or it can be a file when redirection was used.

If you want to read the data your program wrote to stdout via stdin on a subsequent run you can use redirections like this

```
$ program > data.out
```

Will store anything that is written to stdout in the file data.out. Then,

```
$ program < data.out
```

... will make the contents of data.out available to the program in stdin

Please post your code and some more detailed description of what you are trying to do if this isn't what you were trying to achieve.